# A version of Rellich-Kondrachov's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $D$ be a bounded open 
subset with smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$
, $k$ be positive integer, 
and $p \in [1,\infty)$ such that $kp < n$. Let $q\in[1,\dfrac{np}{n-kp})
 $ and put 
$T(u) = u$  for all $u \in W^{k,p}
(D)$ .
Then $T$ is a bounded linear mapping from $W^{k,p}
(D)$ into 
$L^
q
(D)$, and the closure $T(A)$ in $L^
q
(D)$ is compact in $L^
q
(D)$ 
for any bounded subset $A$ in $W^{k,p}
(D)$ .

Where can I find a proof of this theorem? Or give me some hints.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't this the standard Rellich-Kondrachev theorem, as stated (for example) in the book by L. Evans, *Partial differential equations*?

Comment: Which place the theorem you tell stated in?

Comment: No, I checked and Evans proves the case $k=1$. But a very similar result is Theorem 7.26 in the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger, *Elliptic partial differential equations of second order*, 1998.

Comment: This is a classical result and you can get the proof from Adams' book "Sobolev spaces".

Comment: Which theorem on Adams 's book? Can you tell me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case $k=1$ established in Evans is quite enough, since
$$ W^{k,p}(D)\overset{I_1}{\hookrightarrow}W^{1,r}(D)
\overset{I_2}{\hookrightarrow}L^q(D),\quad r=\frac{np}{n-(k-1)p}\,,\;
q\in\bigl[1,\frac{nr}{n-r}\bigr)=\bigl[1,\frac{np}{n-kp}\bigr),$$
with the embedding operators $I_1$ and $I_2\,$, where $I_1$ is just continuous, while $I_2$ is continuous and compact.  Hence so is their composition $I=I_1\circ I_2\,$.